# AngularJS 2 styleUrls: What's up with concatenation?

Tags: css, angular, shadow-dom

My [AngularJS 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS#Releases) application has several style files which I concatenate with a `gulp` task. That's all fine, since they'll end up in a big file I send to the browser in production. My question is about the Angular 2 `@Component` and its `styleUrls` attribute.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'hero',
    templateUrl: 'hero/hero.template.html',
    styleUrls: ['hero/hero.component.css'],

    inputs: ['hero']
})
```

Thanks to shadow [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) emulation in default mode (emulated) the styles defined in the `hero/hero.component.css` are applied only to the component just like I want. My question is, what happens with concatenation? I cannot bundle all the CSS files specified in the multiple `styleUrls` since we'd be defeating the purpose of encapsulation: the styles for a component would leak to the whole document. However, I don't want either to make a call in production for every CSS file a component needs. How can I concatenate those styles (and possibly minify them) so the client gets them all in a single call, and still preserve encapsulation?

Comment: Well, I use typescript and npm to work with angular 2 and I've observed that behind the scenes, all the styleUrls are automatically fetched first, made inline in head and then sent to browsers. Is there a problem with this approach?

Comment: you mean for every component specifying `styleUrls` there's a request fetching each of the files, right? It does work, I wondered though if it could be reduced to a single call in some way (for production environments).

Comment: I believe that the styles should not be concatenated but be bundled with components, e.g. via gulp-inline-ng2-template.

Comment: that sounds reasonable, I'll give a try during this week and post the result here. thanks you

Comment: Is that the best strategy people have come across? Any others to consider?

Answer (score 1):

The template and css files can be bundled along the js files using a system js plugin.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import html from './hero/hero.template.html!text';
import css from './hero/hero.component.css!text';

@Component({
    selector: 'hero',
    template: html,
    styles: [css],
})
export class HeroComponent implements {
}
```